# HMAC postgres error - No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I'm getting below error while using hmac method in postgres. Please help.

```
root@go=# SELECT HMAC('MyPassword','mykey','md5');
ERROR:  42883: function hmac(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT HMAC('MyPassword','mykey','md5');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  ParseFuncOrColumn, parse_func.c:523
Time: 0.703 ms
```

Comment: How did you load `pgcrypto`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You never installed pgcrypto with `CREATE EXTENSION`.
2. You installed pgcrypto in a schema that is not on the `search_path` of database user `root`.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz, i have added extension, it works.
`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto" SCHEMA public;`